# Determining source code filename and line for function using Visual Studio PDB

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, winapi, pdb-files

I'm trying to programmatically determine the filename and line of the source code for a function definition using its address and the pdb database file generated by visual studio for the module the function is defined in.

For instance, I have a function `Lua::asset::get_supported_export_file_extensions` defined in the module `shared.dll` and I want to determine the source code location for it.

To get the relative virtual address (rva) of the function, I subtract the module base address from the absolute virtual function address like so:

```
static MODULEENTRY32 GetModuleInfo(std::uint32_t ProcessID, const char* ModuleName)
{
    void* hSnap = nullptr;
    MODULEENTRY32 Mod32 = {0};

    if ((hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessID)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return Mod32;

    Mod32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    while (Module32Next(hSnap, &Mod32))
    {
        if (!strcmp(ModuleName, Mod32.szModule))
        {
            CloseHandle(hSnap);
            return Mod32;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return {0};
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    auto dllInfo = GetModuleInfo(GetCurrentProcessId(),"shared.dll");
    auto rva = (DWORD)((uint64_t)&Lua::asset::get_supported_export_file_extensions -(uint64_t)dllInfo.modBaseAddr);
    [...]
}
```

This gives me the rva **0x44508** for the function.

To confirm the address, I've tried using the [dbh debugging tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dbh) from the Windows SDK to look up the function's address (as well as the base address for the module):

```
shared [1000000]: enum shared!*get_supported_export_file_extensions*

 index            address     name
     1            1e376c0 :   `Lua::asset::get_supported_export_file_extensions'::`1'::dtor$0
     3            18409c0 :   Lua::asset::get_supported_export_file_extensions

shared [1000000]: scope 18409c0

   name : path\to\object_files\lasset.obj
   addr :        0
   size : 0
  flags : 0
   type : 0
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagNull (0)
    tag : SymTagCompiland (2)
  index : 6
```

I would expect it to give me the same rva if I subtract the base address from the function address, but instead it gives me a rva of `0x18409c0 -0x1000000 = 0x8409c0`

For convenience I will be referring to the addresses as:

```
0x44508 = calculated address
0x8409c0 = dbh address
```

I then used the [Debug Interface Access SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/getting-started-debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2019) to look up both addresses in the pdb to determine why I'm getting differing results:

```
static BOOL find_function_in_pdb(DWORD rva,enum SymTagEnum tag)
{
    std::string pdbFilePath = "path/to/shared.pdb";
    CComPtr<IDiaDataSource> pSource;
    if(FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED)))
        return FALSE;
    auto hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_DiaSource,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IDiaDataSource),
        (void **) &pSource
    );
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return FALSE;

    wchar_t wszFilename[_MAX_PATH];
    mbstowcs(wszFilename,pdbFilePath.data(),sizeof(wszFilename) /sizeof(wszFilename[0]));
    if(FAILED(pSource->loadDataFromPdb(wszFilename)))
        return FALSE;

    IDiaSession *session;
    IDiaSymbol *globalSymbol = nullptr;
    IDiaEnumTables *enumTables = nullptr;
    IDiaEnumSymbolsByAddr *enumSymbolsByAddr = nullptr;
    if(FAILED(pSource->openSession(&session))) 
        return FALSE;

    if(FAILED(session->get_globalScope(&globalSymbol)))
        return FALSE;

    if(FAILED(session->getEnumTables(&enumTables)))
        return FALSE;

    if(FAILED(session->getSymbolsByAddr(&enumSymbolsByAddr)))
        return FALSE;

    IDiaSymbol *symbol;
    if(session->findSymbolByRVA(rva,tag,&symbol) == S_OK)
    {
        BSTR name;
        symbol->get_name(&name);
        std::cout<<"Name: "<<ConvertBSTRToMBS(name)<<std::endl;

        ULONGLONG length = 0;
        if(symbol->get_length(&length) == S_OK)
        {
            IDiaEnumLineNumbers *lineNums[100];
            if(session->findLinesByRVA(rva,length,lineNums) == S_OK)
            {
                auto &l = lineNums[0];
                CComPtr<IDiaLineNumber> line;
                IDiaLineNumber *lineNum;
                ULONG fetched = 0;
                for(uint8_t i=0;i<5;++i) {
                if(l->Next(i,&lineNum,&fetched) == S_OK && fetched == 1)
                {
                    DWORD l;
                    IDiaSourceFile *srcFile;
                    if(lineNum->get_sourceFile(&srcFile) == S_OK)
                    {
                        BSTR fileName;
                        srcFile->get_fileName(&fileName);
                        std::cout<<"File: "<<ConvertBSTRToMBS(fileName)<<std::endl;
                    }
                    if(lineNum->get_lineNumber(&l) == S_OK)
                        std::cout<<"Line: "<<+l<<std::endl;
                    
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    find_function_in_pdb(0x44508 /* calculated address */,SymTagEnum::SymTagPublicSymbol);
    find_function_in_pdb(0x8409c0 /* dbh address */,SymTagEnum::SymTagFunction);
    [...]
}
```

It does actually find both addresses and both point to a symbol with a name matching my function, however the symbol at the calculated address is a `SymTagPublicSymbol` and the symbol at the dbh address is a `SymTagFunction`.

I'm guessing that means that the calculated address is for the public symbol and the dbh address for the private symbol? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/public-and-private-symbols)

So far so good, the problem is the public symbol does **not** have any source code information associated with it, but the private symbol does. Assuming I'm correct so far (which I'm not quite sure about), my question boils down to:

How can I get the private symbol/address from the public symbol/address? I need a solution that I can implement programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimentation I found the solution:

```
IDiaSymbol *publicSymbol;
DWORD publicRva = 0x44508;
if(session->findSymbolByRVA(publicRva,SymTagEnum::SymTagPublicSymbol,&publicSymbol) == S_OK)
{
    DWORD privateRva;
    IDiaSymbol *privateSymbol;
    if(
        publicSymbol->get_targetRelativeVirtualAddress(&privateRva) == S_OK &&
        session->findSymbolByRVA(privateRva,SymTagEnum::SymTagFunction,&privateSymbol) == S_OK
    )
    {
        // Do stuff with private symbol
    }
}
```

`get_targetRelativeVirtualAddress` gives me `0x8409c0`, the address of the private symbol which contains the source code information.

As for why this works, I have no idea. According to the documentation, [get_targetRelativeVirtualAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/idiasymbol-get-targetrelativevirtualaddress?view=vs-2019) is only supposed to be valid for `SymTagThunk` symbols and returns the rva of a "thunk target". I don't think the public symbol *is* a thunk target, but it works without errors and gives me exactly what I need.